# How can Haemophilus influenzae survive and grow alone in the human body?

Tags: microbiology, bacteriology, infection

Haemophilus influenzae gets its name from the fact, that it requires nutrients from blood in order to grow. More specifically, I see it mentioned that in vitro they often exhibit the pheomenon that they don't really grow in plates with blood alone. They do, however, grow when other bacteria are added that causes haemolysis (like Staphylococcus aureus).

H. influenzae is known to cause otitis media, meningitis and pneumonia. How does it get its nutrients in these places? Is there a coinfection with other bacteria that do haemolysis?